# Insanely huge memory leaks when running Python notebook script .ipynb

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, memory-leaks, jupyter-notebook

Today, I've decided to run LDA algorithm with cross-validation library on some n=400 images, k=20 times. In first 10 minutes I have lost over 100 GB of space on my C drive without being able to reclaim it after the process has stopped. However, it is RAM demanding task. It even used 16GB of virtual memory (in pagefile.sys) to run it.

1. I have no idea why did it even need space to run the algorithm
2. It does not delete the temp files after finishing

Where can I find those 100 GB files and release them? I couldn't find it using pretty much any tool available for finding huge files on your drive.
This happened for the first time ever in my programming career.
Any help on how to recover the space would be helpful! :)

Comment: The use of temp files does not constitute a memory leak.

Comment: Ok, so what does? In other words, how can I make sure I do not lose memory when running a Python script?

Comment: A memory leak is when your program allocates *memory* (not disk space) that is not released back to the allocator for reuse after the program is done with it. You can always delete the temp files yourself (independent of whether your program will work properly after you do so), but there is no comparable way to get memory back from an active process.

Comment: So, if I lose disk space from running python algorithm I can just shut down the active process that is using a lot of RAM and potentially clogging my drive and it will revert back. Or even better, restart PC. That should kill all tasks.

Comment: If you are using windows, could you have a look at this location: `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code`?

Comment: This comment helped me a lot. Found a lot of space there!